# OpenCV Write PCA eigenvectors to yaml file, losing precision?

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml, pca

I need to store the OpenCV PCA object (eigenvalues, eigenvectors) for a set of training images to a persistent store, that I can reload for testing later. I am using the OpenCV 2.4 feature [XML/YAML file storages](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html) to write my eigenvectors and eigenvalues matrices to a yaml file. However, when reloading the file and projecting the same input image into the reloaded PCA space I don't get a difference between projections of 0? I believe I'm losing precision somehow  but can't seem to figure out why? I've based my code on an answer given by @Link in his solution "[Saving pca object in opencv"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066370/saving-pca-object-in-opencv)

```
int numPrincipalComponents = db.size()-1;
Mat output1, output2;
PCA pca(matrix, global_mean_vec, CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, numPrincipalComponents);

pca.project(matrix.row(0), output1); //Project first image into orig. PCA

Mat eigenvalues = pca.eigenvalues.clone();
Mat eigenvectors = pca.eigenvectors.clone(); 

//Write matrices to pca_happy.yml
FileStorage fs("./Train/FileStore/pca_happy.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "Eigenvalues" << eigenvalues;
fs << "Eigenvector" << eigenvectors;
fs.release();

//Load matrices from pca_happy.yml
FileStorage fs1("./Train/FileStore/pca_happy.yml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat loadeigenvectors, loadeigenvalues;
fs1["Eigenvalues"] >> eigenvalues;
fs1["Eigenvector"] >> eigenvectors;
fs1.release();

PCA pca2;
pca2.mean = global_mean_vec;
pca2.eigenvalues = loadeigenvalues;
pca2.eigenvectors = loadeigenvectors;

pca2.project(matrix.row(0), output2);

Mat diff;
absdiff(output1, output2, diff);

cout<<sum(diff)[0]<<endl;
```

However the difference is 88.4 and should be 0, as I'm projecting the exact same image. Do I need to store each row of the eigenvector matrix? Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I made a very stupid mistake when setting the eigenvalues, eigenvectors and means or pca2!

```
PCA pca2;
pca2.mean = global_mean_vec;
pca2.eigenvalues = loadeigenvalues;
pca2.eigenvectors = loadeigenvectors;
```

Should be:

```
PCA pca2;
pca2.mean = global_mean_vec.clone();
pca2.eigenvalues = loadeigenvalues.clone();
pca2.eigenvectors = loadeigenvectors.clone();
```

Hope this can help someone else as well!

Answer (score 0):

did you compute the mean vector correctly?
I only made two small modifications: (with my own `matrix`)

```
PCA pca(matrix, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, numPrincipalComponents);//compute mean automatically
pca2.mean = pca.mean;
```

and the `diff` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, PCA2 should be:

```
Mat eigenvalues1,eigenvectors1;
FileStorage fs1("fileName.yml", FileStorage::READ);
//Mat loadeigenvectors, loadeigenvalues;
fs1["Eigenvalues"] >> eigenvalues1;
fs1["Eigenvector"] >> eigenvectors1;
fs1.release();

PCA pca2;
pca2.mean = pca.mean;
pca2.eigenvalues = eigenvalues1;
pca2.eigenvectors = eigenvectors1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to read yaml file using opencv cpp